# Maven Cucumber Reporting Multiple JSON files

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My POM currently looks like,

```
<groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>ExecuteAutomation</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This does generate a report but only with the last feature. I have multiple runners, so I'm trying to figure out either:

A. How do I combine multiple JSON into one report or

B. How do I append on to one JSON file as each test finishes?

Either of these seems like a viable solution, Although I would prefer A because it seems like I'm only missing one line in my pom.xml to do so as I currently am already generating multiple JSON files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the version being used (i.e.  2.8) doesn't support multiple JSON files.

The solution is:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>ExecuteAutomation</projectName>
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsonReports</inputDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Read more at https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting

Answer (score 1):

If you can run bash commands and maybe have **jq** available on the machine, maybe try to generate the reports in files with different names then use jq to merge them back into one file

I do something similar although I don't run parallel and I don't rely on any plugin, I run with the surefire plugin

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested the report name override with --format so that part might be different for you but the idea is the same

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--format=json:target/cucumber_test1.json"
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--format=json:target/cucumber_test2.json"
...

jq -s '[.[][]]' target/cucumber_*.json > target/cucumber.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to complement the previous answer,

you may have both behaviors, append json files to get a completed when you will see how many times a fetarue was reexcuted after getting passed status, or just getting a final repot where the features will only appear once with the latest status after rerun.

I was able to merge the results of the report after rerun just by using

it is more detailed here, in readme file on comments for the plugin:
https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting

hope it helps.